# After Provisioning profiles are made, code signing not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Here are the steps I have taken to get where I am now:

1. Created two certificates in the developer center for APNs development and production (both tied to the App ID I am using with push notifications enabled)
2. Downloaded and installed the certificates into Keychain Access.
3. Created provisioning profiles in developer center for production and development (both pointing to the appropriate App ID)
4. In XCode, under Preferences > Accounts > View Details - I refresh and get the provisioning profiles. It lists two signing identities (development and distribution but not sure if these are correct).
5. Under Build Settings I have the appropriate provisioning profile selected but...

There are NO code signing identities available, except "iPhone Developer"

So my question is, how can I get the right code signing identities listed here so I may publish my app? The app currently working fine in the app store, but I want to switch from a Phonegap build (what I currently have published) to an Xcode build.

Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED! Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing everything correct until you hit step 5. Since provisioning profile are under signing identities, my guess is that since you choose the provisioning profile first it's messing something up.

Try resetting your **Provisioning Profile** to "None". Then select your **Code Signing Identity**.

Comment: Wow. Sadly that made the signing identities I was looking for appear. Thanks so much for that, but now I have a new problem... When I go to build, it gives me the "No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity were found" message. The problem is I don't want to create new certificates and profiles I just want to release an update of my app. Thanks so much!!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use old provisioning profiles that aren't using the new signing identities.

Comment: Okay so I believe I got everything set up properly now. I followed a documentation found on pushwoosh.com for setting it up with them. I am able to select the provisioning profile I want and use a code signing identity to build successfully. Only NOW all of a sudden it has broken my plugins. My device and network info plugins aren't working all of a sudden. I'm getting the "ERROR: plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin Check your mapping in config.xml" Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question. Go ahead and create a new question so you state the entire question in detail and everyone can see it and help.

Answer (score 0):

Under Target -> General Are you selecting the correct "Team"? Without the correct team, your code signing will not be found.

[image]

Please make sure that the Code Signing Identifier under the Build settings for both the **Project** and **Target** MUST be the same.

[image: code signing]

If still can not work, then I think you can clean up the project, close down your XCode project and then reopen. Sometimes it solves the problem this way.

Comment: Under Build Settings for the project I am given a list of code signing identities (automatic and identities in keychain). I am able to select the distribution or development identity that I want here but they do not reflect in the target's build settings. Under the target's build settings I am still only given "iPhone Developer" as a code signing identity. The provisioning profiles are there however.

Comment: Try this: Download the provisioning profiles from the Apple Developer provisioning centre and double click to install the profiles. Close your project and reopen it. See if it is there.